# JQuery Animated Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, animated

It is ridiculously hard to find easy/simple animated text. Like the "Implosion" on this website
http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-text-animation/full_screen_preview/233445
but I'd have to pay for it. Actually any kind of simple onclick text fade in would be very cool. Any suggestions, links, or help?

Comment: Just in case anyone's shy about clicking the link - it is pretty awesome, worth checking out.

Comment: I get not paying for jQuery plugins but he's only asking $5, I'd go with buying the plugin or use fadeIn/fadeOut jQuery effects.

Comment: @Wesley: some may think it's awesome, some may think they sit in a time-machine and are stranded at a old MS-Frontpage-demonstration ^^

Comment: One thing you definitely shouldn't do is decode his plugin and use it without a license.  It's not like it would be really easy to do or anything since it's client sided.

Comment: Please give feedback on the answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its not so hard to create such an effect using jQuery.
Create a single element vor every character, move it somewhere and then animate it back to original position.

A simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/dNXVx/

Comment: Great work... how much do we owe you? :D Seriously though, this is perfect.

Comment: I don't know if it's legal to sell it, maybe MS has a copyright on this effect :D

Comment: The proper term is "required donation".

Answer (score 3):

Just use fadeIn jquery function ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)):

```
$("#button").click(function() {$("#container").fadeIn()});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/cVELa/

Comment: @valipour "Actually any kind of simple onclick text fade in would be very cool."

Comment: the problem is not fading a text in - the effect is far more complex! run effects in the link

Answer (score 0):

Try [Textillate.js](http://textillate.js.org/)! It allows you to animate text with effects such as flash, bounce, shake and more. In all, Textillate.js contains more than 25 effects for you to apply to your text.