# How to make a text effect reproduce on load page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reproduce the effect our friend @Dr. Molle told us on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538546/jquery-animated-text/6538963#). I have a div like this:

```
<div id="start_palmira">
    <span>Palmira Interiores</span>
</div>
```

That I want to reproduce when the window loads. Our friend introduces us to the onclick event of that particular div, and I'm trying to do it on the **onload** event of the page.

I've tried this using jquery:

```
/* Start animation */
$("#start_palmira").ready(
    function fx(o)
    {

      var $o=$(o);
      $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
      $o.css('position','relative');
      $('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
      opacity:0,
      fontSize:84,
      top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
      left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}
   }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:12,top:0,left:0},1000);
});
```

inside the

```
$(document).ready(function()  { ... things happening .... });
```

method. But if I do it like that, my browser doesn't load, and finally it asks me to stop the script that is making my browser go slowly.

I also wanted to fire the event on the **onload** event of the body, but I have doubts on how to handle that.

**NOTE:**
This is the link to the onclik event of the div of our friend. I want it to be an onload event: [The onclick event!](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/dNXVx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/288/

with on load

If you want to apply this event on the whole page then please notice this part :

```
var $o=$('span');
```

this part help you to getting the text that you want to animate.